# grails : update object resulting in updating the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have the following code

```
def allnews = {
    def max = params.next
    def cat = params.cat

    def news = GeneralNews.createCriteria().list {
        eq("category.id", cat.toLong())
        maxResults(max.toInteger())
        order("dateCreated", "desc")
      }
      for(int i=0;i<news.size(); i++ ){
          news.get(i).imageData="";
      }
      render news as JSON
}
```

as you can see in the for loop i'm trying to reset the imageData column so i don't have it on the json .. the result is it's getting deleted from the database entirely .. what is the problem 
and how it getting saved?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it

in Datasource.groovy file in hibernate section you add

```
    hibernate {
    flush.mode="manual" //THIS LINE TURNS OFF DIRTY CHECKING
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'

    show_sql=false



}
```

turn off the flush mode will require you to save always by .save(flush: true)